# Can anyone explain me about q vs fq in amazon cloudsearch api version 2013?

Tags: php, amazon-cloudsearch

```
endpoint/search?q=shelim&fq=(or (not type:'XYZ') (not mod:'ABC'))&return=_all_fields
```

My result returns data for type `XYZ` whereas I have mentioned not to return value for `XYZ` in the query. Is there anything wrong? Also tell me why `q` and `fq` is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is explained in the [Cloudsearch Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/filtering-results.html)

> You use the fq parameter to filter the documents that match the search
>   criteria specified with the q parameter without affecting the
>   relevance scores of the documents included in the search results.
>   Specifying a filter just controls which matching documents are
>   included in the results, it has no effect on how they are scored and
>   sorted.

The `q` parameter is where you enter your actual query.

Concerning your data type criteria, you're basically doing

```
where type != 'XYZ' OR type != 'ABC'
```

You need to use an `AND` condition (`(and (not type:'XYZ') (not mod:'ABC'))`) so documents which don't have type `XYZ` and don't have type `ABC` are filtered out.

With your query, the documents which have type `ABC` are filtered out *but some of those documents have type `XYZ`*. Those are included since you're using an `OR` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But to my case the item of type 'XYZ' will never be of mod 'ABC'.Finally  the query (not (or type:'XYZ' mod:'ABC')) worked for me.